# Как фильтровать по строгому сравнению, но регистронезависимо в search model?

Tags: php, yii2, postgresql9.6

Для условия фильтрации по `like` в модели поиска, в методе  `public function search($params)` можно писать вот так:

```
 $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'tz.name', $this->name])
```

для регистронезависимого вот так:

```
 $query->andFilterWhere(['ilike', 'tz.name', $this->name])
```

А если я хочу строго вот так:

```
 $query->andFilterWhere(['=', 'tz.name', $this->name])
```

но регистронезависимо. То что нужно и как писать?

Comment: $query->andFilterWhere(['REGEX', 'name', '/'.$this->name.'/i']); [ссылка](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/andfilterwhere-and-case-insensivity/72944)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov без регулярок получается никак? А то если полей много, боюсь тормозить регулярка начнёт

Comment: Если не перебарщивать с самой регуляркой (а она у нас супер-простая), и добавить юникод флаг, то можно сравнить по скорости и использовать что лучше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось просто:

```
->andFilterWhere(['=', 'LOWER(tz.name)', mb_strtolower($this->name)])
```